# parse through cell and paste cell contain to adjust cells

Tags: vba, excel

I've tried a million way but couldn't get this (VBA on excel)
I've the following excel spreadsheet the first row is the input and the others are my desired output.
My pre-condition say that can never be more than four levels (3 points). Each level can go for 1 to 99.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxKj6.png

I'm trying to copy and paste each level to the adjustment cells. Any suggestion how to do it with vba. I've figured out how to get the count of the lines and then maybe do a for loop so that each line can be translated into the output form using a sub but that's where I get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the cells you wish to process and run:

```
Sub PointParser()
    Dim r As Range, s As String
    For Each r In Selection
        s = r.Text
        cnt = Len(s) - Len(Replace(s, ".", ""))
        r.Offset(0, 1) = 0
        r.Offset(0, 2) = 0
        r.Offset(0, 3) = 0
        r.Offset(0, 4) = 0
        If cnt = 0 Then
            r.Offset(0, 1) = s
            GoTo NextOne
        End If
        If cnt = 1 And Right(s, 1) = "." Then
            r.Offset(0, 1) = s
            GoTo NextOne
        End If
        ary = Split(s, ".")
        j = 1
        For Each a In ary
            r.Offset(0, j) = a
            j = j + 1
        Next a
NextOne:
    Next r
End Sub
```